# Why does Dr Cuddy agree with Dr House on his method of treatment only after visiting the patient?

Tags: character, analysis, house

House MD: S1,E1.

Dr Cuddy doesn’t agree with Dr House’s way of treating the patient for cerebral vasculitis (D/d,) i.e., by administering steroids to the patient. She walks up to House and delivers the news, then visits the patient in her room and while stepping out agrees with Dr House and says

> You got lucky.

I fail to understand what transpired between the two in this time that she agrees. The patient was only having her meal and asked Dr Cuddy if she’s Dr House ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I fail to understand what transpired between the two in this time that she agrees.

### The patient had seemingly recovered between the time of steroid treatment and Dr. Cuddy visiting her.

When Dr. Cuddy visited the patient she noticed that the patient had color to her, a hearty appetite, was sitting up straight and was smiling, and even wanted to thank Dr. House. All of this together strongly suggested to Dr. Cuddy that the patient was recovering well.

Note: This kind of dynamic is a **continual** theme throughout the series; that being -- House treats the patient in some unorthodox way that most other doctors disagree with but it usually ends up working out by the end of the episode.

Comment: I am trying to get my brain into the play. A lot of things are unexplained and sound like a blabber if the explanation isn’t sought. Thank you so much. :)